# Why does this code doesn't work in jsfiddle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I tried to make this code http://www.w3schools.com/w3css/tryit.asp?filename=tryw3css_accordion work on jsfiddle 
https://jsfiddle.net/u6qdfw5f/ but it doesn't work why ?

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>W3.CSS</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3.css">
<body>

<div class="w3-container">
<h2>Accordions</h2>
<p>An accordion is used to show (and hide) content that is broken into sections:</p>

<div class="w3-accordion w3-light-grey">
    <button onclick="myFunction('Demo1')" class="w3-btn-block w3-left-align w3-show">Open Section 1</button>
    <div id="Demo1" class="w3-accordion-content w3-container w3-show">
    <h4>Section 1</h4>
    <p>Some text..</p>
    </div> 
    <button onclick="myFunction('Demo2')" class="w3-btn-block w3-left-align w3-show">Open Section 2</button>
    <div id="Demo2" class="w3-accordion-content w3-container w3-show">
    <h4>Section 2</h4>
    <p>Some other text..</p>
    </div>
</div>
</div>

<script>
function myFunction(id) {
    var x = document.getElementById(id);
    if (x.className.indexOf("w3-show") == -1) {
        x.className += " w3-show";
    } else { 
        x.className = x.className.replace(" w3-show", "");
    }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: A couple things - the css file doesn't load over `https` and if you try with `http` the browser reports "insecure request".  Try copying the css from the source file and add it in to the fiddle.  You also need to define myFunction in the <head> tag (which you can do with the fiddle javascript settings dropdown.  https://jsfiddle.net/rcode5/u6qdfw5f/4/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is because the `CSS` is not loading. If you check the console you can see an error like `GET https://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3.css net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE`. Add the `CSS` on the right top section of the fiddle.

This happens because that link contains `https` while w3schools website does not have a secured certificate. If you try to access `https://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3.css` on the browser you will get an privacy error. Adding `http` instead of `https` and it will work in browser.

`http` file won't work in jsfiddle `https` because it's considered unsafe. You will get an error in the console like:

```
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://jsfiddle.net/u6qdfw5f/1/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure stylesheet 'http://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3.css'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
```

I've also added the javascript load type to be `No wrap - in <head>` from the javascript dropdown, instead of the default `onLoad`, otherwise you will get an error like `Uncaught ReferenceError: myFunction is not defined`

Updated **[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/u6qdfw5f/1/)**.

Answer (score 1):

Your main issue with the JS code not working is because you've set the 'Load type' in settings to execute when document.ready fires. This means that the `myFunction()` definition is not in scope of the calling `onclick` attribute.

Secondly, the `w3.css` file path in the external files list is incorrect. You used `https://` yet the W3Schools site does not have an SSL certificate so the request fails. You should use a `http://` link instead.

With those changes made, the code works: [**Updated fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/osyevwbr)

You should however note that the code in the W3Schools example is a little outdated. To follow modern best practices you should use unobtrusive event handlers over `on*` attributes, and also you can use the `classList` to toggle classes on and off without the need for an `if` statement. Try this updated version:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.w3-btn-block').forEach(function(el) {
  el.addEventListener('click', function() {
    var x = document.getElementById(this.dataset.target);
    x.classList.toggle('w3-show');
  })
})
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3.css" />

<div class="w3-accordion w3-light-grey">
  <button data-target="Demo1" class="w3-btn-block w3-left-align">
    Open Section 1
  </button>
  <div id="Demo1" class="w3-accordion-content w3-container">
    <p>Some text..</p>
  </div>
  <button data-target="Demo2" class="w3-btn-block w3-left-align">
    Open Section 2
  </button>
  <div id="Demo2" class="w3-accordion-content w3-container">
    <p>Some text..</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Alternatively, as you've tagged the question with jQuery, you could use that:

```js
$('.w3-btn-block').click(function() {
  var x = $(this.dataset.target);
  x.toggleClass('w3-show');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3.css" />

<div class="w3-accordion w3-light-grey">
  <button data-target="#Demo1" class="w3-btn-block w3-left-align">
    Open Section 1
  </button>
  <div id="Demo1" class="w3-accordion-content w3-container">
    <p>Some text..</p>
  </div>
  <button data-target="#Demo2" class="w3-btn-block w3-left-align">
    Open Section 2
  </button>
  <div id="Demo2" class="w3-accordion-content w3-container">
    <p>Some text..</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Also note that I strongly suggest that you do not use W3Schools as a reference. Their tutorials are often out of date - as you can see from the above improvements - and sometimes they're even completely wrong and spread incorrect information.

If you want a good reference for JS code, use [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript), and for jQuery, use the [official documentation](http://api.jquery.com/)